# Dropdown of UI-select in table can't overlay next row

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have a ui-select in a ng-repeat table, i'm having problem to get the dropdown list of ui-select to overlay the next table row. Currently the next row overlays the dropdown list, look at the img link below. thanks

```
<table class="table table-bordered" ng-table="tableTest">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="testing in $data">
            <div>
                <td data-title="Name">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="testing.name" placeholder="Name">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <ui-select ng-model="testing.parent" theme="select2" style="width: 100%">
                            <ui-select-match placeholder="test...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
                            <ui-select-choices repeat="test.name as test in myData | filter: {name: $select.search}">
                                <span ng-bind-html="''+test.name | highlight: $select.search | unsafe"></span>
                            </ui-select-choices>
                        </ui-select>
                    </div>
                    <br><br><br><br><br>
                </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Click 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nszy6.png) to see current output Image.

What I want is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vVKP.png), dropdown list overlay the next row

Please assist

Comment: Provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: I'd showed the code now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the z-index of the `ui-select` dynamically. You need to set the `z-index` of the first `ui-select` the highest, and the last one the least. You can try replacing the line `9` by adding the `z-index` attribute as:

```
<ui-select ng-model="testing.parent" theme="select2" style="width: 100%; z-index: {{100 - $index}}">
```

What this code is doing is adding `z-index` to each `ui-select` by dynamically assigning decreasing values, highest for first and least for the last one.

**EDIT**: You can also try using the same logic on `<tr>` tag as:

```
<tr ng-repeat="testing in $data" style="z-index: {{100 - $index}}">
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, my question wasn't clear, what I means is the dropdown list doesn't display fully. Look at the image I'd shared, beside "Microsoft" in the drop down list, there's many more below. however due to the new row, the list are not showed fully, what I want is the list to overlay new row instead of the new row overlay the dropdown list

Comment: I got your question at the first place. Try using `z-index` to bring the `ui-select` above the next row. You can also try the same logic on `tr` rather than on `ui-select`.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway I've tried that but it still doesn't shows.

Comment: You should first try inspecting the element inside the browser. Right click on the `ui-select` bar, click on inspect element (if you are using Chrome browser), then try setting the `z-index: 100` in `element.style` property on the right top panel after selecting the element in the dom. Try to set this property for the `ui-select`, `ui-select-choices` etc. You should figure out the div which needs the higher z-index. Try it out and let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Using this code <tr ng-repeat="testing in $data" style="z-index: {{100 - $index}}">

I'd tried inspecting the element, and the 1st row is 100 while the 2nd row is 99, which means by right the 1st row properties should overlap the 2nd row, but it doesn't.

I'd tried this link below and added z-index: {{100-$index}} in the <li> element, and it works here.
http://plnkr.co/edit/2K8HuGAJ8EzJWlDaQJSh?p=preview

Comment: Adding the line `<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="person in ctrl.people" style="position: relative; z-index: {{100 - $index}}">` at line number 26 in your `plnkr.co` resolves the issue.

Comment: Can you deploy your code on plnkr? I will make sure it works.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's what I mean over here (plunker) it works, but on my table it doesn't.

Side Note: the plunker is just an example I saw which, I use your code to test, which works.

Anyway thanks, a lot, really appreciate your help, i'm gonna mark yr reply as answer as the logic is right, just that something is wrong with my table. Thanks

Comment: I would love to as it would make my life much easier but I couldn't as it's a client code that i'm working on(would be in trouble if i post it), even the html I showed above is just sample I created as you had request for code. Anyway the table is in an modal page(pop-out) over the main page, which I don't know if it affects. Anyway, still really thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'd solve the problem by adding style="position: fixed into line 8 <div class="form-group">.  This link could help https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/308